# Automatic dependency injection with Spring

Tags: java, spring, dependencies, code-injection

I am currently using CDI (Weld) with tomcat 6 as servlet-container. Having the WeldLifecycleListener within the configuration, doing depencency injection is fairly simple.

My question is: Is there an equivalent of the WeldLifecycleListener for Spring to avoid instantiating beans from the ApplicationContext?

Comment: What do you mean by "avoiding the application context"?

Answer (score 2):

In Spring 3 you can use [JSR-330](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/summary?id=330) annotations such as `@Named` and `@Inject` (see http://blog.springsource.com/2009/09/29/spring-framework-3-0-rc1-released/).

The classes annotated with `@Named` will be automatically detected and instantiated when you enable component scanning by adding the following to the spring configuration file:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="${base-package}" />
```

where `${base-package}` is the package that contains all the components (either directly or in sub-packages).

Comment: Thanks for the answers so far, but my question wasn't how to define beans (java,xml,annotation). That's no problem so far. 

With Spring, i only managed to get dependencies resolved within a bean i get from applicationContext. For example the following works:

ctx = WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(getServletContext());
testBean = (TestBean) ctx.getBean("testBean");

Dependencies within testBean are resolved correctly. However, i can't directly @Inject testBean without calling the allicationContext.

Comment: Just to clarify, you have servlets which are managed by CDI but want Spring to inject dependencies into them? I'm not a CDI expert but I would guess that you have to choose to manage them either through CDI or Spring, otherwise you will have to add custom code to get the spring context and inject the dependency.

Comment: Though maybe if you added `@Component` or `@Controller` to the class you are trying to inject the dependencies in (that is, the class where you are writing `ctx = WebApplicationContext...`).

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about `WeldLifecycleListener` but can give pointers for automatic dependency injection

1. You could use the autowire attribute in Spring beans in spring config file . Read about this [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-autowire)
2. You could also use the [@Autowired](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation) annotation for autowiring by type and @Qualifier along with it for looking up beans by name .
3. [@Resource](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-resource-annotation) annotation can be used for auto-wiring by name.
4. If you don't want to define any beans in Spring config, use the component scan to auto detect components and use the annotation @Component on your bean - This + @Autowire/@Resource will simplify your configurations.